# ArrayList created from ListView with HashMap duplicates instead of Adding

Tags: listview, arraylist, duplicates

So, i have a ListView created by JSON Parsing, and i want once an item is selected from the ListView to be added to another ArrayList, where i use HashMap because it is a bundle of data. The problem is that if I select one it works fine, BUT once I select a second one then my ArrayList will have the SECOND one TWO times, and if i do it again the third one THREE and so on. I am attaching that part of the code below, any help would be appreciated.

```
  lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long id) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Bookmarked",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();


//adding the data from the list view to the HashMap object

                    HashMap<String, String> obj = (HashMap<String, String>) adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    String name = (String) obj.get("name");
                    String rating = (String) obj.get("rating");
                    String summary = (String) obj.get("summary");
                    String date = (String) obj.get("publ. date");
                    String type = (String) obj.get("type");
                    String suggested_link = (String) obj.get("suggested_link_text");
                    String link = (String) obj.get("link");


                    bookmarked.put("rating", rating);
                    bookmarked.put("name", name);
                    bookmarked.put("summary", summary);
                    bookmarked.put("publ. date", date);
                    bookmarked.put("type", type);
                    bookmarked.put("suggested_link_text", suggested_link);
                    bookmarked.put("link", link);


//the ArrayList that contains the HashMap data
                    selected.add(bookmarked);

                    Log.v("Selected: ", selected.toString());

                }});
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're overwriting the `bookmarked` object on every click and you're adding this same object to the list every time.
The solution would be to create a new `bookmarked` object everytime :

```
HashMap<String, String> bookmarked = new HashMap<String, String>();
bookmarked.put("rating", rating);
                bookmarked.put("name", name);
                bookmarked.put("summary", summary);
                bookmarked.put("publ. date", date);
                bookmarked.put("type", type);
                bookmarked.put("suggested_link_text", suggested_link);
                bookmarked.put("link", link);
```

Comment: that fixed it! Thanks alot i appreciate it!:)